# How to connect ODBC source to on-premises data gateway in power bi server?

Tags: mysql, odbc, power-bi-report-server, data-gateway, onpremises-gateway

Every time I am trying to create an on-premises data source using ODBC, I am getting this error. Can anyone explain to me what the problem is??

[This error occurs every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84pM4.png)

[The ODBC connection used for the same report in power bi desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDOK6.png)

Comment: I do not think that basic authentication is for mysql, that more sounds like a http authentication. However, we really do not know your infrastructure, so difficult to tell you what has gone wrong.

Comment: I am using ODBC connection properties here. I have tried using MySQL connection string but it did not work as well. I can't find anything on the internet as well. But, thanks for the effort.

Comment: To be honest, I think you should ask this question on the dedicated microsoft support forums, not here. SO is for software development related questions and this is about configuring stuff, not about programming.